# Xamarin.Forms - Xamarin.Forms.Maps broken references in Droid Project

Tags: xamarin.forms, visual-studio-2017

I need to implement Map functionality into an application that I'm building.
And I was folliwing [this guide](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/user-interface/map/).

I downloaded the package and did all of the configuration. 
I haven't implemented the Map class into my project yet, I only did the configuration required for both platforms (Android and iOS).

The Portable project and the iOS project are fine, the problem here is the Android project.

It has some broken references, these ones:

[image]

And when I try to compile the Android project, I get this error and these warnings:
[image]

Can anybody give me a hand? Thanks in advance.

EDIT:
As a sidenote, I'm using the Sdk installed by Android Studio, and that one has the latest Google Play Services installed.

UPDATE:
I just upgraded the version of my Xamarin.GooglePlayServices one by one (the one listed up there in the first image) for some reason it downloaded a really old version of those. So I just upgraded them, and it seems those references are fine now.

But I still get the error:
The "ResolveLibraryProjectImports" tasks failed unexpectedly.

Comment: 1/ start a new xforms/pcl project.
2/ update ONLY the xam forms nugget.
3/ do NOT update the android nugets
4/ add 'xf maps nuget' to solution
5/ set droid minimum sdk to 4.4
6/ rebuild pcl
7/ rebuild droid

post back and let me know

Answer (score 0):

**SOLUTION:**

I unloaded the Android project, added this:

```
<UseShortFileNames>True</UseShortFileNames>
```

To every property group in the .csproj file.

Load my android project back, and it all worked fine now.